# What package is responsible for bash completion for systemd/systemctl on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, systemd, auto-completion

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed locally, and it has bash completion for `systemctl` subcommands by default. But when I start an instance of Ubuntu Server 18.04 on Digital Ocean, there is no bash completion for `systemctl` subcommands. I'd expect some missing package like `systemd-completion`, but on my local Ubuntu I have only these packages installed:

```
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64                          229-4ubuntu21.2                                          amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd0:amd64                             229-4ubuntu21.2                                          amd64        systemd utility library
ii  libsystemd0:i386                              229-4ubuntu21.2                                          i386         systemd utility library
ii  systemd                                       229-4ubuntu21.2                                          amd64        system and service manager
ii  systemd-shim                                  9-1bzr4ubuntu1                                           amd64        shim for systemd
ii  systemd-sysv                                  229-4ubuntu21.2                                          amd64        system and service manager - SysV links
```

and completion works. The `bash-completion` package is installed on both machines.

Also, at `/etc/bash_completion.d/` of my local 16.04 machine, I don't see any related systemctl completion files

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   408 сер 21  2015 cryptdisks
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   323 бер 18  2016 desktop-file-validate
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2384 сер 13  2010 dkms
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   439 сер 11  2017 git-prompt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 11144 тра 11  2017 grub
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   736 тра  7  2013 insserv
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6596 лют 19 23:06 libreoffice.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   553 лют  2  2016 openvpn
```

So, what package should I install to get bash completion for `systemctl` subcommands?
Maybe I should turn something on in bash configs somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this answer by first, finding out which package provides `systemctl`:

```
$ dpkg -S $(type -p systemctl)
systemd: /bin/systemctl
```

Then looking at the contents of the `systemd` package, I see:

```
$ dpkg -L systemd
...<snip>...
/usr/share/bash-completion
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-run
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/timedatectl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-analyze
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-cgtop
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-delta
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-path
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/journalctl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-detect-virt
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/localectl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/networkctl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/hostnamectl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/bootctl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-cat
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemd-cgls
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl       <---
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/busctl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/loginctl
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about `/usr/share/bash-completion`  location. The file you mentioned is already present, and the `ip` command is also missing bash completion. So looks like it's not a systemd-specific issue, and I should look for some wider bash configuration problem.